# template alternative for user defined literals

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, user-defined-literals

I created a template class, and I wanted to use a user defined literals.

My code:

```
template<int base = 10>
class MyClass
{
   // class code
};

// template<int base> /* Not allowed */
MyClass<17> operator "" _G(const char* param, size_t length)
{
    string temp(param, length);
    return MyClass<17> (temp);
}

int main()
{
    MyClass<17> A = "75AD"_G;
    A.print();
}
```

As a result of my search, I knew that user user defined literals are limited and cannot be used with most templates such the one above.

**Is there an alternative solution, or user defined literals are impossible in this case?**

Note: `base` can be `2` to `30`.

Comment: I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work - besides that you mix case (`_g` vs `_G`).

Comment: If you want to make your result type dependent on the literal itself I believe that it isn't available in c++11 standard. If you are using gnu compiler you could make use of its extension in literals that allow you define literal as follows `template <class C, C... Cs> auto operator ""_sl() `. To make base dependent on template parameter there you'll need to use some sfinae.

Comment: It is impossible to know what type you want `"75AD"_G` to be just by looking at the literal. The context you are using it in (such as the assignment operator) is irrelevant, An expression must be of a defined type on its own.

Comment: It is however easy to create a non-template helper class, make a UDL operator that returns that class, and have your `MyClass` to accept it as constructor parameter. This looks like having the functionality you want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's actually possible with a bit of indirection. The idea is to delay the template deduction up to the point where you have the type information.

```
struct MyClassCtor {
  std::string param;

  template<int base>
  operator MyClass<base>() {
    return param;
  }
};

MyClassCtor operator "" _G(const char* param, size_t length)
{
    return {std::string(param, length)};
}
```

It's an example of the ["Return Type Resolver"](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Return_Type_Resolver) idiom.

Of course, bear in mind that means that `auto a = 345_G` will not create a variable of `MyClass<>` type, although it could be passed to any function which expects one. That can either be a bug or a feature, depending on how you look at it.